# If A ⊆ C then A ∪ (B ∩ C) = (A ∪ B) ∩ C

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that x $\in$ A $\cup$ $(B \cap C)$

Then x $\in$ $B \cap C$

Then x $\in$ A or (x $\in$ B and x $\in$ C)

Then x $\in$ A or x $\in$ B and x $\in$ A or x $\in$ C

But how can i proof that (A $\cup$ B) $\cap$ C is valid? and also proof this that A $\cup$ (B $\cap$ C) = (A $\cup$ B) $\cap$ C

Comment: If $A\subseteq C$ then $A \cup C = C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the distributive law to expand the left hand side:

$$A \cup (B \cap C) = (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C) = (A \cup B) \cap C$$

as $(A \cup C) = C$ because $A$ is a subset of $C$.

Answer (score 1):

> I $\overset{\color{red}{\text{assume}}}{\require{cancel}\cancel{\text{know}\!\!\!}~}$ that $x \in A \cup (B \cap C)$ .
>
> Then $\color{red}{x\in A\text{ or}}$ $x \in B \cap C$
>
> Then $x \in A\text{ or }(x \in B\text{ and }x \in C)$
>
> Then $\color{red}(x \in A\text{ or }x \in B\color{red})\text{ and }\color{red}(x \in A\text{ or }x \in C\color{red})$

You have been given $A\subseteq C$ as a premise, and this means: if $x\in A$, then $x\in C$.

Thus: $(x\in A\text{ or }x\in B)\text{ and }(x\in C\text{ or }x\in C)$

$~~\vdots$

Therefore the assumption entails $x\in (A\cup B)\cap C$

---

You must also demonstrate the converse: that $x\in (A\cup B)\cap C$ entails $x\in A\cup(B\cap C)$ too.

- Let us assume that $x\in(A\cup B)\cap C$.  Then $(x\in A\text{ or }x\in B)\text{ or }x\in C$.  If $x\in A$ then (show) $x\in A\cup (B\cap C)$, and if $x\in B$ then (show)  $x\in A\cup (B\cap C)$.  Therefore  $x\in A\cup (B\cap C)$ in either case.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a Venn diagram.  It will provide the way.  There are three disjoint pieces $A-B$, $A\cap B$, $(B\cap C)-A$.